# How to filter UISearchBar for multiple strings in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have an array of `struct`'s which each have a title and subtitle:

```
struct searchItem {
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
}

let itemArray: [searchItem] = [
        searchItem(title: "Bob", subtitle: "Man"),
        searchItem(title: "Susan", subtitle: "Woman"),
        searchItem(title: "Joe", subtitle: "Man")
]

var filteredArray = [searchItem]()
```

Each `searchItem`'s `title` and `subtitle` are used to create a `tableViewCell` in a `tableViewController`, with a `UISearchBar` at the top:

[simulator image of tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mudu.png)

I need to somehow filter the `itemArray` based on the search term, and each `searchItem`'s `title` and `subtitle`,  So either the search term "Man", or "Bob" will return the individual Bob.

How does one go about doing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much do you have for the searching? Have you implemented UISearchController yet? Or do you just need a way to filter it?

Comment: I've created a UISearchController, and currently have an empty updateSearchResultsForSearchController function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your array with `filter` method of swift array. When you use the filter it **returns** and **another array** of items depends on your **searchText**. So you should add searched items to your new `filteredArray` and **reload** your `tableView`.

```
if let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text{
            let searchText = searchBarText.lowercaseString
            filteredArray = self. itemArray.filter({$0.title.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil})
            filteredArray += self.itemArray.filter({$0. subtitle.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil})
            tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I do this filtering for both the title, and subtitle string? If I just repeat the action for both it will return any searchItems that satisfy BOTH strings, rather than EITHER

Comment: It's simple mate, just filter again with the subtitle strings and add them to your filtered array. I updated my answer for your case.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was afraid that I might get duplicates if I filtered both, but I realized that would only happen if I had an item whose title was the same as another item's subtitle, which isn't the case.

Comment: Have a nice coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version :

```
if let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text{
            let searchText = searchBarText.lowercaseString
            filteredArray = categoryArray.filter ({$0.title.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil})
            filteredArray += categoryArray.filter ({$0.sybtitle.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil})
            tableView.reloadData()
}
```